# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike' after command virutalenv mydir on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04, attributeerror

Virtualenv does not work.

```
virtualenv mydir
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike'


python3-pip:
  Installed: 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.6

python3-dev:
  Installed: 3.5.1-3

lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, was your question answered? If so, could you please accept and upvote the answer? If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 3):

`os.PathLike` doesn't exist in Python 3.5—it was [introduced in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike), which was [released in 2016](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html).

Your options are:

1. Update your Python version to something released in the past 5 years.
2. Use the built-in [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) instead of `virtualenv`—a subset of `virtualenv`'s functionality
3. Use a more recent version of `pip`.

Why this last one? Your issue has actually been surfaced [on GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2001); it emerges because of underspecified versions in package requirements. More recent versions of `pip` know how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've been using pipenv on Ubuntu16.04 and I had the same error. You can  try upgrading PIP and virtualenv.

Comment: It would be helpful if you indicated which versions of PIP and virtualenv to upgrade to if, in fact, that is a solution.

Comment: Right now I have these versions: Python 3.7.9 / pip 21.0.1 / virtualenv 20.4.2 / pipenv 2020.11.15.